# How to force html element click wireup from js in dynamically loaded page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Wish I could think of a better way to phrase the question...

Using JQuery.Ajax to dynamically load content in a simple web app with a static nav bar on top and a content area below.  When the user clicks a button on the nav bar I load the requested page's html into the content div using ajax.  Works great.

I am using a somewhat elaborate admin theme that is based on Bootstrap and other libararies to style the app.  I put all the css and js refs in the parent page, and in the child pages I just use the classes with no reference to the css or js.

When the html child is loaded it renders correctly based on the css referenced by the parent, this makes sense to me because after it is loaded it is actually part of the parent page, and so it has access to everything in the parent.

My problem is a click handler defined in a js file is not attached to an element.  I can confirm this using F12 in chrome.  If, however,  I place a reference to the js in the child then the click handler does get wired up and it works fine.

I'm guessing the reason that it does not work is that when the child is loaded nothing tells 'the system' to wire up the event as defined in the js file.

Here is the html in the child page:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-mini content-refresh">
<i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
</a>
```

Here is the js function (it's a dummy function that does nothing) that is referenced in the parent page:

```
$(".content-refresh").click(function (e) {
    alert('refresh');
    e.preventDefault();
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.find("i").addClass("icon-spin");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $el.find("i").removeClass("icon-spin");
    }, 2000);
});
```

As stated, when I include the js in the child it works perfectly, when only referenced in the parent all css styling works but the click handler does not.

I don't know if there is a downside to including the js in the child, and maybe that's the only solution.  Since the resource is already loaded I'm assuming the browser won't load it again, but there are may js files and I would like to reference them only once in the parent it that is possible.

How can I get the click event to wireup after I dynamically load the page when I only reference the js file on the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

To attach an event handler for an element now and in the future.
You can use.

```
$(document).on("click", ".content-refresh", function (e) {
    alert('refresh');
    e.preventDefault();
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.find("i").addClass("icon-spin");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $el.find("i").removeClass("icon-spin");
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Well, that worked perfectly.  Could someone explain to me why it works?